# Change menu layout on certain width repsonsive design WordPress

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, menubar

I'm developing an responsive WordPress theme.

On a regular computer (full-size) a menu is visiblie like:

```
<div id="header-menu" role="complementary">    
     <ul>
         <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1&link_before=<span>&link_after=</span>'); ?>
     </ul>
</div>
```

On a certain width (for mobile devices and tablets I'd like to replace this menu with a  menu like this one:

```
<div id="header-menu-mobile" role="complementary">
       <form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
       <?php

       $args1e = array(
        'depth'            => 1,
        'child_of'         => 0,
        'selected'         => 0,
        'echo'             => 1,
        'name'             => 'page_id');

        wp_dropdown_pages( $args1e ); ?>

       </form>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("page_id");
    function onCatChange()
    {
        if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 )
        {
            location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
            ?>/?page_id="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
    --></script>
</div>
```

I could in the css for a certain width set "header-menu" to hidden... and make "header-menu-mobile" set to visible. I'm kinda tired in my head and there's probably a better solution to make this work.

Any ideas on how?

Kind regards
Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about your `CSS` idea. Stick with it.
Use this standard CSS structure to make your website responsive.

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll stick with it! The media queris you mention is from Twitter Boostrap? I hade some other queries widths but these seems to work great too so I change to these aswell.. I only added: @media (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape).

Answer (score 0):

try  `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`
it tells you about user operating system and browser. You may frame your code accordingly
example -

```
if $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == 'win 8'
echo $menu_for_windows ;
else if $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =='opera mini'
echo $menu_for_mobile
```

and so on ..

also

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo $browser['platform'] ; exit;
```

can tell you the user platform

Comment: Nice idea.. But Isn't it a problem with so many devices out there to add them all and what about future devices?